# LOCK TABLES in wordpress using $wpdb

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

am trying to run the following code on wordpress

```
 $sql ="LOCK TABLES some_table LOW_PRIORITY WRITE;"."\n";
 $sql .=" CALL some_stored_pro('somevalue');"."\n";
 $sql .=" UNLOCK TABLES;"."\n";
 $wpdb->query($sql);
```

am getting the following error
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL get_one_us_city('aa');
 UNLOCK TABLES' at line 2"

when i modify the query above so that it runs only 
    CALL "some_stored_pro('somevalue');"
it works perfectly

my question: can we run LOCK TABLES script using $wpdb object?

Comment: the table is running on MYISAM engine

Comment: You can only execute 1 query per `$wp->query()` call

Comment: hek2mgl - thanks, the following works
    $sql ="LOCK TABLES some_table LOW_PRIORITY WRITE;"."\n";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
    $sql =" CALL some_stored_pro('somevalue');"."\n";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
    $sql =" UNLOCK TABLES;"."\n";
    $wpdb->query($sql);

Comment: Ok, then I'll answer this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only execute 1 query per $wp->query(). Separate the SQL into 3 queries and call them one by one:

```
$queries = array(
    "LOCK TABLES some_table LOW_PRIORITY WRITE",
    "CALL some_stored_pro('somevalue')",
    "UNLOCK TABLES"
);

foreach($queries as $query) {
    $wpdb->query($query);
}
```

However, I don't know your reasons to call `LOCK TABLES` but mostly it isn't required.

Comment: FYI - am using the lock because i want to run hundreds of processes that are getting a single record from the DB then querying Wikipedia API with this record and getting more information that will be used as attributes in the same record. kind of filling up blank columns in the table.
since the processes can not communicate am using the database to ensure that their is no repetition